# SUMIFS with multipe checks on columns EXCEL

Tags: excel-formula

I have a question regarding excel, for which I could not find an answer on the internet:

I have a data source sheet like this:

Cat  - V1  - V2  -

01   | 10  | 11  |
02   | 12  | 10  |
03   | 10  | 23  |
01   | 11  | 10  |
02   | 23  | 30  |
03   | 30  | 12  |

Then there is a result sheet on which I want to do some calculations:

Category  |   number of times V1 is bigger than V2

01        |  1
02        |  1
03        |  1

So I need a formula that counts the number of times V1 is bigger than V2 per category. I tried this:
COUNTIFS(B:B;"<"&C:C;A:A;D1)
Where the value of D1 is category 01. This obviously doesn't work because now the total amount of comun B and C are compared.

Can anybody help me with this? (the story is actually a bit more complex with multiple SUMIFS, but my issue is to do a check per row and create a  summary on the results. The source data is imported over and over, so  I need to do the calculations on a different sheet)

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$6=D1)*($B$1:$B$6>$C$1:$C$6))
```

I don't recomend you to use entire columns in formula, i.e. `B:B`, because it makes formula very slow.

Comment: Thanks simoco, this is exactly what I was looking for. I use the B:B notation because i never now in advance how much lines of data will be imported (I deliver the sheet to different site managers who will use it themselves). Would you perhaps also have a suggestion on how to program this dynamically?

Comment: in that case use `B:B`, or alternatively you can create vba UDF. If should be faster